# panel.style.left in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to do this using jquery :

```
 panel.style.left = '150px'
```

How can I do this ?

I tried this:

```
  var panel = $('#Panel1');
  panel.position().left = 150;
```

but It didn't work

Comment: Why did you give the answer to the person that posted the same thing I did, after me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way:

```
panel.css("left", 150);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try: `panel.css('left', '150px');`

Check the docs on the [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method.